# MATLAB event function to pass me a flag when it sends one to ode45 at the same time

Tags: matlab, events, ode

I am using ode45 and want to stop integration by event function when the solution hits zero. What I need is event function to return ME a "flag" . That means whenever event sends a stop sign to ode45 to stop, this stop sign (whatever it is) is sent to me as well.

thanks

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. If the events function detects your zeros and stops the integration, `ode45` halts and returns its output. What more do you need? What is this flag and where exactly do you expect it to go? You might check out some of my answers to related questions that provide examples of how to use (and how not to use) event detection: [\[1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15992197/2278029), [\[2\]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16681767/2278029), [\[3\]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20429657/2278029), and [\[4\]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17370733/2278029).

Comment: thank you. the flag is IE in this statement
[T,Y,TE,YE,IE] = solver(odefun,tspan,y0,options)
I need it for some investigations of stability for numerical calculations of problem of my interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`ode45` documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html):

> `[T,Y,TE,YE,IE] = solver(odefun,tspan,y0,options)` solves as above while
>   also finding where functions of `(t,y)`, called event functions, are
>   zero. For each event function, you specify whether the integration is
>   to terminate at a zero and whether the direction of the zero crossing
>   matters. Do this by setting the `'Events'` property to a function, e.g.,
>   `events` or `@events`, and creating a function
>   `[value,isterminal,direction] = events(t,y)`. For the ith event function
>   in `events`,
>
> - `value(i)` is the value of the function.
> - `isterminal(i) = 1`, if the integration is to terminate at a zero of this event >function and 0 otherwise.
> - `direction(i) = 0` if all zeros are to be computed (the default), `+1` if only the zeros where the event function increases, and `-1` if only the zeros where the event function decreases.
>
> Corresponding entries in `TE`, `YE`, and `IE` return, respectively, the time at which an
>   event occurs, the solution at the time of the event, and the index `i`
>   of the event function that vanishes.

The event function is set through the `options` argument, with the [`odeset`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) function