# ODE with time dependent input, How to speed Up without using interpolation?

Tags: performance, matlab, ode, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve a system of ODEs and my input excitation is a function of time.

I have been using `interp1` inside the integration function, but this doesn't seems like a very efficient way to do this. I know it is not, because once I change the input excitation to a `sin` function, which does not require an `interp1` call inside the function, I get much much faster results. But doing interpolation every step takes about 10–20 times longer to converge. So, is there a better way of solving ODEs for arbitrary time dependent excitation, without needing to do interpolation or some other tricks to speed up?

I am just copying a modified version of a [simple example from The MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#bu3l43b) here:

Input Excitation is a `gradually increasing sin` function, but after some time later it becomes a `constant amplitude sin` function.

```
Dt   = 0.01;   % sampling time step
Amp0 = 2;      % Final Amplitude of signal
Dur_G = 10;    % Duration of gradually increasing part of signal 
Dur_tot = 25;  % Duration of total signal
t_G = 0 : Dt : Dur_G; % time of gradual part 
A = linspace(0, Amp0, length(t_G));
carrier_1 = sin(5*t_G); % Unit Normal Signal
carrier_A0 = Amp0*sin(5*t_G);
out_G = A.*carrier_1;   % Gradually Increasing Signal
% Total Signal with Gradual Constant Amplitude Parts
t_C = Dur_G+Dt:Dt:Dur_tot; % time of constant part
out_C = Amp0*sin(5*t_C);   % Signal of constant part
ft = [t_G t_C];    % total time 
f = [out_G out_C]; % total signal
figure; plot(ft, f, '-b'); % input excitation


function dydt = myode(t,y,ft,f)
f = interp1(ft,f,t); % Interpolate the data set (ft,f) at time t
g = 2;               % a constant
dydt = -f.*y + g;    % Evaluate ODE at time t

tspan = [1 5]; ic = 1;
opts = odeset('RelTol',1e-2,'AbsTol',1e-4);
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) myode(t,y,ft,f), tspan, ic, opts);

figure;
plot(t,y);
```

Note that I explained only first part of my problem above, which is solving system for a gradually increasing `sin` function. 
In the second part, I need to solve it for an arbitrary input excitation (e.g., a ground acceleration input).

Answer (score 0):

For this example, you could use [`griddedInterpolant`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant-class.html) class to get a bit of a speed-up:

```
ft = linspace(0,5,25);
f = ft.^2 - ft - 3;
Fp = griddedInterpolant(ft,f);
gt = linspace(1,6,25);
g = 3*sin(gt-0.25);
Gp = griddedInterpolant(gt,g);

tspan = [1 5];
ic = 1;
opts = odeset('RelTol',1e-2,'AbsTol',1e-4);
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y)myode(t,y,Fp,Gp),tspan,ic,opts);

figure;
plot(t,y);
```

The ODE function is then:

```
function dydt = myode(t,y,Fp,Gp)
f = Fp(t);        % Interpolate the data set (ft,f) at time t
g = Gp(t);        % Interpolate the data set (gt,g) at time t
dydt = -f.*y + g; % Evaluate ODE at time t
```

On my system with R2015b, the call to `ode45` is about three times faster (0.011 sec vs. 0.035 sec) for your example. You could get a bit more speed by switching to `ode23`. You can read more about the `griddedInterpolant` class [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-gridded-data.html#bs2o5n7-1).

If your actual system, discretely switches between inputs particular points in time, then you should probably solve the problem piecewise by integrating each case separately. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20429065/2278029) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17356037/2278029). If the system switches based on the value of the state variable(s), then you should use [event location](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13755352/2278029)). However, if "solving ODEs for random time dependent excitation" means that you're adding random noise to the system, then you have an [SDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation) rather than an ODE, which is a completely different beast.

Comment: Thank you Horchler. I need to explain more about the problem but this comment area is limited in terms of words, so should I post it as an answer? Ohh Okay I will edit my question... Could you please check it?

Comment: @IsmailBahadirKuzucu: I don't have time to look at your updated question right now. I may have time later this week/weekend.

Comment: Yeah I understand Horchler. I will look forward to getting your insights on the question. Thank you for your time.